# nth derivative of function $f^{1/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

I know the following Leibniz's rule
$$(fg)^{(n)} = \sum_{k = 0}^n {n\choose k}f^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}$$
this formula can be generalized to the product of $m$ differentiable functions $f_1,f_2,\dots,f_m$
$$(f_1f_2\cdots f_m)^{(n)} = \sum_{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_m=n} {n\choose k_1,k_2,\dots,k_m}\prod_{1\leq j\leq m} f_j^{(k_j)}$$
where $\displaystyle {n\choose k_1,k_2,\dots,k_m}=\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!\cdots k_m!}.$

Which I have been able to prove by induction, but my question is: What happens if I want to make the nth derivative of $f^{1/2}$? Will it have the following form

$$(f^{1/2})^{(n)}=\sum a_rf^{1/2-r_0}(f')^{r_1}(f'')^{r_2}\cdots (f^{(n)})^{r_n}\;?$$
where also $1/2=1/2-r_0+r_1+\dots+r_n$. It is clear that I start thinking about this particular case and then generalize to an $f^{m/n}$.

Comment: Can you do $(f^{1/2})'$ and $(f^{1/2})''$ ?  Do these have the form you expect?

Comment: Yes of course, doing the calculations it makes sense to think in the way I mention above, I tried up to $(f^{1/2})'''$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we consider the $n$-th derivative of a *composition* $g\circ f$ of functions $f$ and $g$ with $g(x)=x^{\frac{1}{2}}$. A formula to calculate the $n$-th derivative of composite functions is stated as Theorem 8.1 in H.W. Gould's *[Combinatorial Identities](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B018DY2B9C)* called:

**Hoppe Form of Generalized Chain Rule**.

Let $D_f$ represent differentiation with respect to $f$ and $f=f(x)$. Hence $D^n_x g(f)$ is the $n$-th derivative of $g$ with respect to $x$.  The following is valid for $n\geq 1$:
\begin{align*}
D_x^n g(f)=\sum_{k=1}^nD_f^kg(f)\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}f^{k-j}D_x^nf^j\tag{1}
\end{align*}

We obtain from (1) with $g(f)=f^{\frac{1}{2}}$
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{D_x^nf^{\frac{1}{2}}}
&=\sum_{k=1}^nD_f^k f^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}f^{k-j}D_x^nf^j\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{4^k(2k-1)}\frac{(2k)!}{k!}f^{\frac{1}{2}-k}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\\
&\qquad\quad\cdot\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}f^{k-j}D_x^nf^j\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{4^k(2k-1)}\binom{2k}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^{j+1}\binom{k}{j}f^{\frac{1}{2}-j}D_x^nf^j\tag{3}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=1}^nf^{\frac{1}{2}-j}D_x^nf^j\sum_{k=j}^n(-1)^{j+1}\frac{1}{4^k(2k-1)}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{k}{j}}\tag{4}
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we calculate $D_f^k f^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and obtain
  \begin{align*}
  D_f^kf^{\frac{1}{2}}&=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdots\left(\frac{1}{2}-k+1\right)f^{\frac{1}{2}-k}\\
  &=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2^k}\,1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2k-3) f^{\frac{1}{2}-k}\\
  &=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2^k(2k-1)}(2k-1)!!f^{\frac{1}{2}-k}\\
  &=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2^k(2k-1)}\frac{(2k)!}{(2k)!!}f^{\frac{1}{2}-k}\\
  &=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{4^k(2k-1)}\frac{(2k)!}{k!}f^{\frac{1}{2}-k}
  \end{align*}
- In (3) we make some simplifications.
- In (4) we change the order of summation to reduce the number of terms with the differentiation operator.

**Plausibility check: $n=2$:** We obtain manually for $n=2$ by conveniently mixing differential operator and prime notation as well as not writing the argument $x$.
\begin{align*}
D_x f^{\frac{1}{2}}&=\frac{1}{2}f^{-\frac{1}{2}}f^{\prime}\\
\color{blue}{D_x^2 f^{\frac{1}{2}}}&=\frac{1}{2}D_x\left(f^{-\frac{1}{2}}f^{\prime}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(f^{-\frac{1}{2}}f^{\prime\prime}-\frac{1}{2}f^{-\frac{3}{2}}\left(f^{\prime}\right)^2\right)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2}f^{-\frac{1}{2}}f^{\prime\prime}-\frac{1}{4}f^{-\frac{3}{2}}\left(f^{\prime}\right)^2}\tag{5}
\end{align*}
We calculate the second derivative according to Hoppes formula (4) and obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{D_x^2 f^{\frac{1}{2}}}
&=\sum_{j=1}^2(-1)^{j+1}f^{\frac{1}{2}-j}D_x^2f^j\sum_{k=j}^2\frac{1}{4^k(2k-1)}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{k}{j}\\
&=f^{-\frac{1}{2}}D_x^2f\sum_{k=1}^2\frac{1}{4^k(2k-1)}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{k}{1}\\
&\qquad-f^{-\frac{3}{2}}D_x^2f^2\sum_{k=2}^2\frac{1}{4^k(2k-1)}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{k}{2}\\
&=f^{-\frac{1}{2}}f^{\prime\prime}\left(\frac{1}{4}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}+\frac{1}{16\cdot 3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1}\right)\\
&\qquad -f^{-\frac{3}{2}}D_x^2f^2\left(\frac{1}{16\cdot 3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}\right)\\
&=f^{-\frac{1}{2}}f^{\prime\prime}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{1}{8}f^{-\frac{3}{2}}\left(2D_x\left(ff^{\prime}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{3}{4}f^{-\frac{1}{2}}f^{\prime\prime}-\frac{1}{4}f^{-\frac{3}{2}}\left(\left(f^{\prime}\right)^2+ff^{\prime\prime}\right)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2}f^{-\frac{1}{2}}f^{\prime\prime}-\frac{1}{4}f^{-\frac{3}{2}}\left(f^{\prime}\right)^2}
\end{align*}
in accordance with (5).

Comment: There should be $(-1)^{j + 1}$ in (3) and (4) and $(f')^2$ in the last line of (5). In terms of the Bell polynomials,
$$(\sqrt f \, )^{(n)} =
\sum_{k = 1}^n (-1)^k \left( -\frac 1 2 \right)_{\! k} f^{1/2 - k}
 B_{n, k}(f', \ldots, f^{(n - k + 1)})$$
(where $(a)_k$ is the rising factorial).

Comment: @Maxim: Many thanks, I've corrected the typos. You might want to add an answer regarding Bell polynomials which are the typical application in this context.

Comment: perfect answer!

Comment: @Algebrology: Thanks your nice comment and the credit! :-)

Comment: Thank you very much @MarkusScheuer for giving you the time to do it in detail, and to all of you for your comments, I will also read about Bell polynomials to understand Maxim's comment much better.

Comment: @Zaragosa: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is useful. :-)